# google sheets importxml resource at url not found - Yahoo Finance

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I tried to get Walgreen's number of full-time employees from Yahoo Finance using importxml like so:

```
=importxml("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/WBA/profile", "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/section/div[1]/div/div/p[2]/span[6]/span")
```

[image]

I have used the function successfully in getting other figures from Yahoo Finance. Example (market cap):

```
=mid(importxml("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/WBA", "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span"),1,6)+0
```

But with the number of employees (and, by the way, also the trailing twelve months' (ttm) revenues) - I get this error.

Without VBA, with which I am not familiar, how can this be fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This site is built client side by javascript, not server side. Therefore, native functions are inoperative.

You have to extract the json inside the source and parse it.

The object is named `root.App.main` inside the source.

To get employees for instance

```
function fullTimeEmployees(url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/WBA/profile'){
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.match(/root.App.main = ([\s\S\w]+?);\n/)
  if (!jsonString || jsonString.length == 1) return;
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString[1].trim())
  Logger.log(data.context.dispatcher.stores.QuoteSummaryStore.assetProfile.fullTimeEmployees)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! Two questions: (1) Why does it work in some cases? (2) Is it possible to get the data from the JSON without VBA (perhaps a function? some parameters?)? I am (clearly) not a programmer but I am familiar with some basics (I know what a JSON is... )

Comment: Some values ​​are available in the source code, and it also depends on the code (not sure why). But all the values ​​are available in the json. I have completed my answer.